# How to do efficient inserts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, insert

When I insert a new object to the DB I tie it with a relationship to another, by doing another db lookup, I'd like to remove this extra step for efficiency, I.E How can I set a relationship to another using just the ID, rather than having to fetch the whole object from the DB? e.g.:

```
Car C = new Car();
C.Person = db.person.find(PersonID); //unnecessary lookup
//I'd like to do: C.setPersonID(personID);
db.cars.add(C);
db.saveChanges();
```

where model:

```
class Car
{
   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that its a one-to-one relationship, you could do this:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
    public CarConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(i => i.Id);
        HasRequired(i => i.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(i => i.PersonId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Then to add a new car with a person using only the person's Id and also assuming that the person with that Id is existing:

```
using (var ctx = new CarContext())
{
    var car = new Car();
    car.PersonId = 5;
    ctx.Cars.Add(car);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

You may find this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/01/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx) useful.

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather not change to using custom contexts, I'm just using a BaseDBContext. So I like the idea of a set Accessor for the ID property. I'm wondering if I can create a method setPersonID(myID) { Person p = new Person; p.id = myId; this.Person = p; }

Comment: Not sure if that's possible since without explicitly declaring the foreign key you won't be able to set the relationship using the Id.

Comment: You could add the SetPersonId(int personId) method on the Car class which you use to set the Id. Not sure though if that is what you mean.

Comment: yes thats what I mean, of course there's no personId property so I'm guessing you have to instantiant the Person object and set its id

Comment: It just seems like EF would have catered for this more elegantly

Comment: Well as far as I know other ORMs I've used (OpenAccess, XPO) doesn't have a way to do it without explicitly specifying the foreign key similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreign keys and set the foreign key property accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this to confirm, but I believe there is a Convention based ID system used by Entity Framework. This may well automatically do what you don't want to happen.

```
class Car
{
   public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
   public virtual Int32   PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

I was going to post code from the NerdDinner project where I have seen this before (http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) but you can look it up as it is fairly attribute-laden code.